# Nginx redirects to an extra subdirectory

Tags: nginx

I have a local site installed with VVV that I've installed in a subdirectory to try and mimic the production environment.

`http://localtest.dev/m/`

Pages are working as expected

`http://localtest.dev/m/some-page/`

But requests to wp-admin redirect to a URL with an extra directory in the path

`http://localtest.dev/m/wp-admin -> http://localtest.dev/m/m/wp-admin/`

My localtest.conf is as follows:

```
server {
# Determines the port number that nginx will listen to for this
# server configuration. 80 is the default http port.
listen       80;

# Listen for HTTPS requests as well
listen       443 ssl;

# Tells nginx what domain name should trigger this configuration. If
# you would like multiple domains or subdomains, they can be space
# delimited here. See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
server_name  localtest.dev ~^localtest\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.xip\.io$;

# Tells nginx which directory the files for this domain are located
root         /srv/www/localtest/htdocs;
index       index.php;
# Subdirectory location settings

location /m/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /m/index.php?$args;
}

# Includes a basic WordPress configuration to help with the common
# rules needed by a web server to deal with WordPress properly.
include /etc/nginx/nginx-wp-common.conf;
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove '/m' from '/m/index.php?$args;'

Comment: Why? What will this do? Can you add more of an explanation please - the post was autoflagged as low quality.

Comment: I believe you are starting with location /m/ and then going to location /m/index.php?$args.  This is causing the /m/m/index.php?$args.